# Why is join equivalent to intersect on tables with 0 attributes?

Tags: database, relational-database

From Date's Introduction to Database Systems (8th ed., p. 186, edited slightly):

> Consider {X1, X2, ..., Xm}, {Y1, Y2, ..., Yn}, {Z1, Z2, ...Zp} as
>   three composite attributes, X, Y, Z respectively. Then the natural
>   join of a and b, `a JOIN B` is a relation with the heading {X, Y, Z{
>   and body consisting of all the tuples {X x, Y y, Z z} such that a
>   tuple appears in a with X value x and Y value y and a tuple appears in
>   b with Y value y and Z value z.
>
> If m = p = 0 (meaning a and b are of the same type), then `a JOIN b` degenerates to `a INTERSECT b`.

How does this degeneration work?

Image:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTERSECT is just JOIN when the argument attribute sets are the same. TIMES is just JOIN when the argument attribute sets are disjoint. Both argument attribute sets empty is just a special case. (That is both INTERSECT & TIMES.)

But the empty sets for *m* = *p* = 0 in the quote aren't the attribute sets of the arguments, they are the sets of attributes that are unique to the left argument *a* and the right argument *b*. When these sets are empty the only attributes are common ones, ie the argument attribute sets are the same. The empty set for *n* = 0 is the common attributes, ie *a* & *b* are disjoint.

It is clearer to avoid this obscure business of "considering as composite attributes". For *a* with attribute set A and *b* with attribute set B, *a* JOIN *b* (has attribute set A U B and) holds the set of tuples t where there exist tuples ta & tb where ta IN *a* and tb IN *b* and t = ta ∪ tb. When A = B we have INTERSECT and when A ∩ B = {} we have TIMES.